# Eleições para Moderadores da Comunidade 2020 - Resultado

Tags: debate, eleição

A [4ª eleição do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/4) chegou ao fim. Depois da contagem de votos, nós temos 2 novos moderadores:

[image: Guilherme Nascimento] [image: Wallace Maxters]

Essa é nossa nova [equipe de moderação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). É hora de dar boas vindas, e parabéns, a quem chega. Obrigado também a todos os outros candidatos, que se dispuseram a ajudar ainda mais o SOpt.

Para ver mais detalhes, basta fazer download do [arquivo de auditoria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/4), ou [ver o resumo online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6549318631686144/0).

Comment: Que sorte. Ou que bom que houve algum esforço da comunidade pra ter dois candidatos viáveis (não teria). A gente sabia da dificuldade que seria isso acontecer por esse motivo eu fui crítico da eleição. A gente que está no dia dia do site e presta atenção ao detalhes sabe o que está acontecendo, isso não deveria ser ignorado. Agora seremos 8 mods.

Comment: Parabéns aos dois e que aconteçam mudanças expressivas  ... !

Comment: Muito agradecido a todos que votaram, independente em quem votou, a participação nessa eleição foi "recorde". Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Houve recorde de número de votos?

Comment: @Costamilam https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1

Comment: Meus Parabéns. Que vocês tragam ideia novas e benéficas para a plataforma e principalmente para os usuários.

Comment: @Maniero me explica uma coisa por favor? Se eles entraram como moderadores do site, por que você ainda é moderador? A eleição é para adicionar novos moderadores ou para substituir os moderados antigos?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Adicionar, esse é o motivo, junto com o fato de não ter candidatos viáveis interessados, que a eleição não fez sentido.

Comment: @Maniero então se a eleição é para adicionar e não substituir, por que demora tanto tempo pra fazê-la? Não seria melhor fazer a eleição a cada 6 meses por exemplo ou abrir vaga para moderador conforme a necessidade (conforme o peso do site sob os moderadores aumenta)?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 conforme eu te disse e falei em alguns lugares, essa eleição não faz sentido, não precisava adicionar ninguém.

Comment: Ata, entendi agora.

Comment: Uma dúvida, houve troca na moderação? Parabêns manos wall-e e guilherme

Comment: Parabéns pessoal, os dois que votei! Vocês merecem.

Comment: Parabéns aos eleitos. 
Tenha ótimo trabalho! Abraço!

Answer (score 20):

Parabéns aos dois eleitos! Pode contar com os moderadores atuais para ajudar no que precisarem principalmente no começo, e espero que a jornada seja proveitosa pra vocês e para todos.

Comment: Obrigado, jovem.

Comment: Obrigado pelo suporte nesse momento de iniciação!

Answer (score 17):

Parabéns aos vencedores!

Como recompensa, agora vocês vão se juntar ao time de alvos preferenciais de ataques por parte de usuários novatos e mesmo de usuários experientes, terão que se envolver em temas espinhosos e tóxicos e ainda terão um número interminável de sinalizações para lidar. E claro, não receberão um único centavo por isso!

Boa sorte aos novos moderadores nessa caminhada.

Comment: There is no spoon.

Comment: Obrigado. PS: uma dica de um colega do site a anos atrás que vivo tentando seguir: seja como a água :)

Comment: Ou... "Corra em zigue zague" :p

Answer (score 9):

Parabéns aos dois eleitos! Podem contar conosco, para ajudarmos no que precisarem.
Que a jornada seja proveitosa para todos.